# openssl decrypt function doesn't work correctly

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I wrote this function by looking wikiopenssl and it was working fine when I tried to use it in main func. Then I wrote another function to take just script to be decrypted. Here is my function:

```
std::string ofxLibcrypto::decrypt(std::string ciphertext) {

unsigned char *plaintext;
unsigned char *binarytobedecrypted;

hex2stream(ciphertext, ciphertext);

for(int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++){
    binarytobedecrypted[i] = ciphertext[i];
}

int lenplaintext = decrypt(binarytobedecrypted, strlen((char*)binarytobedecrypted), k, v, plaintext);

std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(plaintext));

clean();

ofLogVerbose("ofxLibcrypto.cpp") << "decrypted";

return str.substr(0, lenplaintext);
}
```

hex2stream is a function to decode base16 string to binary and works fine. First parameter is string to be decoded and second parameter is holding binary values. I see that problem is in the decrypt func and here is the decrypt func:

```
int ofxLibcrypto::decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext) {

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
int len;
int plaintext_len;

if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 1";

if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 2";

if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len)) handleErrors();
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 3";

plaintext_len = len;
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 4";

if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 5";

plaintext_len += len;
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 6";

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 7";

return plaintext_len;
}
```

LogNotices are there for detecting where is the problem and it prints out "To detect 4" and then app crashes. I tried a lot to solve but i can not find a solution. Thanks everyone already.

Comment: Encrypted data isn't a string, you can't use `strlen` on it

Comment: @user253751 i made that line like ` int lenplaintext = decrypt((unsigned char*)ciphertext.c_str(), ciphertext.length(), k, v, plaintext); ` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`plaintext` is uninitialized.  Hence, it's pointing to garbage memory.  Aka undefined behavior when `EVP_DecryptUpdate` writes to it.

Also, you are forgetting to allocate `binarytobedecrypted` as well.

Do this. It's late, but I'm guessing you should give plaintext some extra padding for whatever block size your encrypt algorithm operates with.

```
binarytobedecrypted = new unsigned char[ciphertext.size()+1];
plaintext = new unsigned char[(ciphertext.size() + 128];
```

Then make sure you null terminate after you write to the buffer if you consider that data to be a "string".

```
if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
{
    handleErrors();
}
else
{
    plaintext[len] = '\0';
}
ofLogNotice("IDB") << "To detect 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my decrypt function to this:

```
std::string ofxLibcrypto::decrypt(std::string ciphertext) {
unsigned char empty[] = { 0 };
unsigned char *plaintext = empty;
hex2stream(ciphertext, ciphertext);
int lenplaintext = decrypt((unsigned char *)ciphertext.c_str(), 
(int)ciphertext.length(), k, v, plaintext);
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(plaintext));
clean();
ofLogVerbose("ofxLibcrypto.cpp") << "decrypted";

return str.substr(0, lenplaintext);
}
```

After this, the same problem occurred again but I found out that problem was plain text's -the text which encrypted- length. It works fine for > 24 chars.